# Geronimo vs Glassfish

Tags: glassfish, solr, activemq-classic, derby, geronimo

For a production environment, is Apache Geronimo better for applications that uses ActiveMQ, Derby, Solr?

Answer (score 6):

In short if you want a lightweight deployment container use Geronimo (it's based on Apache and Jetty). If you want an "all in one do everything for you JEE5 container" then Glassfish is the way to go, but it's no small thing.

Finally, question why you want to have a container at all. What is it that you need to do that really needs a full on container? A lot of highly scalable solutions use a mixture of Spring and Jetty to achieve their aims. Very light, very agile.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Dropwizard](http://dropwizard.codahale.com) for an extremely lightweight solution. Very impressive.

Answer (score 0):

All applications and hardware is different. So even if you find a comparison it doesn't really mean much. What you ultimately need to do is do your own load testing, on hardware that is the same or very similar to Production.

You can use http://grinder.sourceforge.net/ or something like that to produce the load.